# PDO row count - num_rows equivalent

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm moving PHP code from mysql to ms sql server.
This will execute my query:

```
  $r = $db_conn->prepare($sql);
  $r->execute();
```

Before I start processing, I need to count how many rows were returned.

old code:

```
$r->num_rows;
```

new code:

```
$rows  = $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rcount = count($rows);
```

All good, but when I try to access values from 1st row I'm getting nothing...

```
try {
    $row = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exception $ex) {   
    return 0;
}
```

I need to repoint to 1st row in my recordset after doing the count, how can I do this without having to requery the database again?

I'm new to PHP, sorry for dumb and probably obvious question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php, not sure if that works with sql-server though for `select`s. It doesnt for `mysql`.

Comment: Hi there - thanks but tried already, doesn't work with sql server selects either. Would be nice if it did...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way in PDO to reset the pointer. You could execute the query again, but given that you've already fetched all the data with your call to `fetchAll`, that is wasteful. Instead, to access the data, simply loop over the `$rows` array e.g.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do something
}
```

Note that if you expect an exception on `fetch`, it is likely you might get one on `fetchAll` too, so you should wrap the call to `fetchAll` in a try/catch block:

```
try {
    $rows = $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (Exception $ex) {   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for quick reply. So I can't go back to row1 in $r recordset again and then do $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   one by one?    That's what my old code does so I'm trying to make as little changes as possible.

Comment: @jacknomiz unfortunately, no. Your only option to allow that would be to execute the query again.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach, if you use [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), is to use [PDOStatement::rowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-rowcount?view=sql-server-2017) and [client-side cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017). With this type of cursor row count is available after a query is executed, but this type of cursor should be used for small (medium) result sets.

```
<?php
# Connection
$server    = 'server\instance,port';
$database  = 'master';
$uid       = 'uid';
$pwd       = 'pwd';

# PDO Connection
try {
    # SQL authentication
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
    # Windows authentication
    #$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

# Client-side cursor
try {
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL, 
        PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED
    );
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM master.sys.server_principals", $options);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Row count: '.$stmt->rowCount().'<br>';
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        echo 'Login name: '.$row['name'].'<br>';
    }    
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    die( "Error executing query".$e->getMessage() );
}

# End
$stmt = null;
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Good try, but for sql server rowCount doesn't work on selects. Nick's approach works, many thanks to both of you for your help. Cheers.

Comment: @jacknomiz It is working example, tested with PHP 7.1.12 (32-bit), SQL Server 2012 and pdo_sqlsrv 4.3.0+9904. As a note, if you try to call a stored procedure, you may need to put `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in this procedure. This will prevent SQL Server to return informational message as result set. Thanks.